# MYSQL: Join list of values into a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have list of predefined values `Cash`, `Bank`, `Card`, `Cheque` called `payment modes` *(no db table for them)*.

Each `payments` will have it's mode.

```
+-----------+
+ Payments  +
+-----------+
+ id        +
+ amount    +
+ date      +
+ mode      +
+-----------+
```

The below query will not show `mode` that are not in the `payments` table. If for example no payment is made through `cheque`, then it will not be in the result.

```
select p.mode, SUM(p.amount) 'total'
from payments p
```

I also found out about `Table Value Constructor` but I'm not sure if its supported in MySql as I'm having syntax error.

```
select p.mode, SUM(p.amount)
from (
    VALUES
      ('Cash'),
      ('Card'),
      ('Cheque'),
      ('Bank')
 ) as m(name) 
 left join payments p on m.name = p.mode
group by p.mode
```

Is there a way to have a query that gets all the mode regardless if they are not present in the `payments` table? I need a result like:

```
++++++++++++++++++++
+ mode     | total +
++++++++++++++++++++
+ cash     | 100   +
+ cheque   | 0     +
+ bank     | 0     +
+ card     | 300   +
++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Add some rows of sample table data and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you can construct the table using `union all`:

```
select m.mode, SUM(p.amount)
from (select 'Cash' as mode union all
      select 'Card' union all
      select 'Cheque' union all
      select 'Bank'
     ) m left join
     payments p
     on m.mode = p.mode
group by m.mode;
```

Notes:

- I changed `name` to `mode` so the column with the same information has the same name.
- The `group by` key needs to be from the *first* name, not the *second* (that is `m.mode` instead of `p.mode`).
- If you want `0` instead of `NULL`, then use `coalesce(sum(p.amount), 0)`.
- You might want to consider a reference table that contains the mode values.

Comment: I don't think m(mode) is valid syntax?

Comment: @Gordon Thank you! I've tried your answer but I'm having a syntax error. Maybe it's not supported in MySql? I think I need to just add the table for modes.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
  m.mode, 
  SUM(p.amount) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      m.Cash as mode 
    FROM 
      (
        VALUES 
          ('cash'), 
          ('card'), 
          ('cheque'), 
          ('bank')
      ) as m
  ) as m 
  left join payments p on m.mode = p.mode 
group by 
  m.mode
```

You need two aliases and you must use the first value of your array (`Cash`) in nested select as selected column.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth checking your version of MySQL if the VALUES approach isn't working. It was only introduced from MySQL 8.0.19 , so anyone on an earlier issue will need to use the UNION ALL approach.