# Grouping data by week and days

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to regroup my data by week then by days of week . this is my code

```
$pp=Path::join('reservations', function($join){
$join->on('reservations.path_id', '=', 'paths.id')  
->where('reservations.state','=',1);})
->where('paths.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
->whereBetween('departure_date', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
->get()
->groupBy(function($date)  {
return Carbon::parse($date->departure_date)->format('d'); // grouping by days
})->toArray();
```

this is my output [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFYg8.png)
but I would like for the results to be presented like

```
Monday => some data ..
Tuesday => some data ..
Wednesday => some data ...
```

Comment: `->format('l')` will give you the day name

Comment: it work fine thnx .. sir if i want to get data from this array how i can do foreach loop ?

Comment: did can i give alias to days name ?

Answer (score 0):

use mysql [DateTimeFunctions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html):

```
->groupBy(DB::raw('DAYNAME(departure_date)')
```

you can use:  (DAYOFMONTH) to return the day order in month

or DAYOFWEEK to return the day order in week,
or DAYOFYEAR to return the day order in year,

and lot of option to group by day format

edit:

to add an alias:

```
->select('*',DB::raw('DAYNAME(departure_date) as weekDay')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('weekDay'))->get();
```

Comment: my result become like picture below did can i change this scaping by some alias ? look picture                                                                 https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/23/3/1591178143-week.png

Comment: my code become like this : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/23/3/1591179494-code.png        but i had this problem : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/23/3/1591179401-prob.png     did u have any solution ?

Comment: you have two problems here
1- ->groupBy(DB::raw('weekDay')) not ->groupBy(DB::raw('DAYNAME(departure_date)')
2- get() must comes at the end of query ... not before

Comment: i changed it to : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/23/3/1591183619-codee.png     
   but i had this error : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/23/3/1591183421-error.png

Comment: you must do this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49230235/10573560

Comment: okey sir i'ts fine now thnx , in my case i want to multiplied the price of path by the reservation accepted .. for example : i have in this week just 1 path created at wednesday, his price 15 and i have two reservations accepted i want my result become "Monday => 0"  "Tuesday=> 0" "Wednesday => 15*2 "  etc .. how i can do it ?

Comment: in your select... add DB::raw('mytable.myColumn * myTable.myColumne as myAlias')

Comment: DB::raw('') allows you to write pure sql

Comment: something like >select('*',DB::raw('DAYNAME(departure_date) as weekDay',
DB::raw('(reservations.accepted * paths.price) as price'))

Comment: i optimize my code  : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/23/3/1591197145-aftero.png    ... to get this result : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/23/3/1591197258-afterop.png     but the problem is the data returned is just for the first path .. for example in my case i have two paths on saturday but the result returned is just for the first path on saturday .. did you have any solution to get all the paths per day ?

Comment: sure ... add paths.id to select and to group statements

Comment: i add thnx sir .. my output become : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/23/3/1591200804-result.png                              can you give me solution to get this output      {
            "id": 41,
            "weekDay": "Friday",
            "revenus": 17
        },   {  "id": 1,
            "weekDay": "Saturday",
            "revenus": 13+16+30 } ,

Comment: sure ... remove path.id from select, also remove your computed column, replace it with:
DB::raw('SUM(paths.price * paths.placed_approved) as sumRevenus')

Comment: great thnx sir :)

Comment: the last thing sir , how can i have this result   {
            "weekDay": "Monday",
            "sumRevenus": 0
        }, {
            "weekDay": "Tuesday",
            "sumRevenus": 0
        }, {
            "weekDay": "Wednesday",
            "sumRevenus": 0
        },{"weekDay": "Friday",
            "sumRevenus": 17
        }, etc...   even the days that are not have path presented with 0 in sumRevenus ?

Comment: there in no easy way to do that ... but nothing is impossible ...i 'am sure you will enjoy solving it ...  the base idea is to make constructed table as sub query and join it with your qeury!
the constructed table shall have the names of the weekDays

Comment: here how to join sub query https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins
see Subquery Joins

Comment: and here how you make constructed table:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48400927/10573560

Comment: did you mean i must create real a table in my BD contains my weekDays or just a virtual table ?

Comment: of course not ... it much like sub query with in memory table , constructed tables are meant to use for short join like joinnig with day week names

Comment: did you make it?